# Migration notice from mSO not updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, migration-notice

So I was looking at a post just migrated from mSO, and it had this post notice:

> migrated from meta.stackoverflow.com 5 mins ago
>
> This question came
> from our discussion, support, and feature requests site for
> meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites.

Given that this site is now the meta site for Stack Exchange, it should probably be updated to talk about the meta site of Stack Overflow.